# Извлечение по ключу

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются следующие таблицы:

1. ТЕСТ1

   - *id* **PK**
   - *name*
2. ТЕСТ2

   - *id_ТЕСТ1* **FK REFERENCES ТЕСТ1(id)**

Каким образом получить данные с другой таблицы по внешнему ключу? Нижеприведённым?

```
SELECT * FROM `ТЕСТ1` where `id` = `id_ТЕСТ1`
```

Или для ключей имеется иной способ получения данных из таблиц?

Comment: А для чего вам "иной способ", чем плох этот?

Comment: @user200192 это не единственный способ, потому и спрашиваю, что именно вас интересует.

Comment: @Кнопкатык а можно, пожалуйста, показать как другим образом извлекаются данные по ключу или хотя бы ссылку для ознакомления

Comment: @user200192 Вы ответите сначала, чем вас не устраивает этот?

Comment: @Кнопкатык  ну, вам сейчас не понять людей, которые не понимают вещей, которые у вас уже заложены как естественное явление:). ну, а вообще, кажется, что вроде бы такой способ неправильной чтоль, ну, или как минимум имеется более рациональный способ.

Comment: @user200192 ну почему же, я понимаю ваше состояние и знаю, что в нём важно задавать себе вопрос "зачем" :) Вышеприведённый запрос неверен и не выполнится. Отсюда и вопрос, что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выборка может идти по любым столбцам, в том числе и по ключевым. Соотношения полей в запросе мы пишем основываясь на логике связей, которую мы знаем. Да, в большинстве случаев мы наше знание о связи оформляем в виде внешних ключей, что бы база то же это понимала и могла проверить не пытаются ли в таблицы записать противоречивые данные. Т.е. например удалить запись из родительской таблицы для которой существуют записи в дочерней или что в дочернюю не пытаются вставить записи с несуществующими в родительской значениями ключа.

Запрос может быть написан и выполнен вне зависимости от существования внешнего ключа. Вы думаю имели ввиду такой запрос:

```
select *
  from ТЕСТ1
  join ТЕСТ2 on id = id_ТЕСТ1
```